# What is the difference between a[x] and a[x, :] in Python for multidimensional (numpy) arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

If `a` is a multidimensional Python array (e.g. `a = numpy.zeros((5, 5))`) and `x` is an integer, how is `a[x, :]` different than `a[x]` in Python (do both of these expressions not evaluate to `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` for `a` as in the example)?

Comment: For one thing, according to the zen of python, "Explicit is better than implicit." `a[x, :]` is explicitly asking for all the values along axis 1 for axis 0. When you are working with higher dimensional arrays, that explicit call can be important

Comment: @G.Anderson do you mean _along axis x_? Or do I not get something in the `a[x, :]` syntax?

Comment: No real difference.  The : is implied, or added automatically as needed.  But it may add clarity to human readers.

Comment: @GAnderson By that argument you then should also write `a[x:x,:]`.